# How can I get frequency information in wavelet?

Tags: wavelet, time-frequency

I am working in image processing. I am confused while getting into wavelet. I applied the fft2() function on Lena image and I got frequency information for the same. But when I applied bior4.4, a popular bi-orthogonal wavelet, I got edge information HORIZONTAL, VERTICAL and DIAGONAL orientation. May you plz. tell me how to get frequency information in wavelet? How time-frequency is localized in bior4.4 wavelet after two level decomposition for Lena image?